# How to validate JLabel in Swing while using FTPClient

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel, ftp-client

I want to update a JLabel each time with the name of the file  which I am downloading using FTPClient. I tried `repaint()`, `validate()`, `revalidate()`, `first invalidate() and immediately validate()/revalidate()` but still nothing is working.

My Code goes as follows:

```
if(ae.getActionCommand()=="Download"){

    int[] row_indexes=table.getSelectedRows();

    notifylb.setText("Downloading files");
    this.validate();

    for(int i=0;i<row_indexes.length;i++)
    {
         String fn=table.getValueAt(row_indexes[i], 0).toString();  

         notifylb.setText("Downloading: "+fn);  // fn contains filename
         this.validate();

         this.downloadFtpfile(fn);  

    }

    notifylb.setText("SUCCESSFULLY DOWNLOADED FILE(s) !");
    this.validate();
}
```

Comment: Make sure you update your label on [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Also read [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html).

Comment: @Max: I agree strongly with your suggestion about updating the label on the EDT, but my guess is that he is already doing this, but that his problem is that he's doing everything else on the EDT as well. Also his problem above has nothing to do with painting in AWT and Swing other than that this is also done on the EDT.

Comment: 'Painting in AWT and Swing' intention is to stop guessing game of combinations of repaint(), validate(), revalidate() etc.

Comment: @Max: OK, I'll buy that.

Comment: Post above edited: removed "need solution urgently" statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hovercraft-Full-Of-Eels explain very clear, but if you need the code, here it is how to write it.

```
final JButton finalButton = button; // this is your button will trigger download
final JLabel finalLabel = finalLabel;
final JTable finalTable = table;


if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Download"))
{
    finalButton.setEnabled(false); //disable button, so user can not start it for twice until ftp finished.
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            int[] row_indexes = finalTable.getSelectedRows();

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    finalLabel.setText("Downloading files");
                }
            });

            for(int i = 0; i < row_indexes.length; i++)
            {
                final String fn = finalTable.getValueAt(row_indexes[i], 0).toString();

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        finalLabel.setText("Downloading: " + fn);  // fn contains filename
                    }
                });

                this.downloadFtpfile(fn);
            }

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    finalLabel.setText("SUCCESSFULLY DOWNLOADED FILE(s) !");
                    finalButton.setEnabled(true); //enable the button
                }
            });
        }
    });
    thread.start();
};
```

Comment: So is it like whatever written in
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() runs in background.. i.e. like small different threads..

Comment: yes, swing is not thread safe, you any update to swing ui, you have to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() which means update it later. you can find more detail explain from here: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html

Comment: @KapilJituri _whatever written in SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() runs in background_ no, just the opposite: whatever runs there is executed **on** the EDT (read the api doc for details :-) So never-ever do anything lengthy there.

Comment: @Kapil: Yep kleopatra is always right when it comes to Swing stuff. Please see example of SwingWorker below.

Comment: thank you guys for your wonderful reply...
finally my app is complete & is running as expected :)

Answer (score 4):

Suggestions:

- Don't use `==` to compare Strings. Instead use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` methods. The `==` operator returns true if the two String ***objects*** are the same, but this isn't what matters to you, but rather you want to check if both Strings hold the same characters in the same order, and this is what the two methods above check.
- You're currently downloading your files on the Swing event dispatch thread or EDT, and this will not only prevent your JLabel from updating but will also cause your GUI to freeze since this thread is responsible for drawing all Swing graphics including its own components, and for Swing interaction with the user.
- Calling `repaint()`, `revalidate()`, `invalidate()`, etc... will do nothing to solve this.
- To solve this, do the downloading or any long-running process in a background thread. One way to do this is by creating a new Thread, loading it with a Runnable, and calling start, but there's a better way that is tailor made for Swing GUI's and that's to create a SwingWorker object and do your background coding in its `doInBackground()` method. The [SwingWorker tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) can help you figure out how to do this, and if you get stuck in your attempt, please come on back with your code.
- You'll probably not want to mention your urgency as this often has the opposite effect intended. Please remember that we are all volunteers, that your urgency is truly *your* urgency not ours, and that no one likes to feel rushed or pressured to do something for someone else, especially volunteers.

Best of luck and welcome to stackoverflow.

**Edit**
Since you've seen an example of using plain Threads, I figured I'd post an example of what doing this with a SwingWorker object could look like:

```
  if (ae.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Download")) {
     final int[] row_indexes = table.getSelectedRows();
     notifylb.setText("Downloading files");

     final List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
     for (int i = 0; i < row_indexes.length; i++) {
        fileNames.add(table.getValueAt(row_indexes[i], 0).toString());
     }
     SwingWorker<String, String> downloadSwingWorker = new SwingWorker<String, String>(){
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
           for (String fileName : fileNames) {
              publish("Downloading: " + fileName);
              downloadFtpfile(fileName);
           }
           return "SUCCESSFULLY DOWNLOADED FILE(s) !";
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
           for (String text : chunks) {
              notifylb.setText(text);
           }
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
           try {
              String text = get();
              notifylb.setText(text);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (ExecutionException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
     };

     downloadSwingWorker.execute();
  }
```

Edit 2: corrected as per kleopatra's suggestion

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft for your reply. Downloading of files and all the stuff is working fine but only problem is with the updating GUI. I do not know much about Swing event dispatch thread & EDT. I will read the stuff on your link n try it out.

Comment: @KapilJituri: note SwingWorker example

Comment: beware: don't access unsynchronized Swing component properties inside doInBackground. To be on the safe side, you would collect the _values_ (vs. their indices) of the selected cells beforehand

Comment: @kleopatra: ayyy, didn't see that bug... correcting immediately.

Comment: @kleopatra: please let me know if the edit is OK. Thanks!! /Pete